# Canada to India via Rome, Italy

Tags: canada, italy, alitalia

I am landing in Canada on my immigrant visa and I will stay here for a couple of days. Then I will board flight to India which has a stop in Rome, Italy. Do I need any kind of visa for the stop in Rome? My stop is at FCO airport for 3 hours. My airlines is AlItalia.